# convert SQL result into Hash

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

For following SQL query:

```
SELECT users.name, posts.title
FROM users
INNER JOIN posts 
ON posts.user_id = users.id
```

I got array of result something like below:

```
name title
foo  post_a
foo  post_b
foo  post_c
bar  post_d
bar  post_e
```

But, I want to group it using user's name, i.e. post titles by for example named 'foo'. So the resultant hash representation should look like:

```
{
  :foo => [ post_a, post_b, post_c ],
  :bar => { post_d, post_e ] 
}
```

How can I do it the Ruby way?

Answer (score 1):

look on [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function

```
SELECT user.name,  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT post.title
                 ORDER BY post.title DESC SEPARATOR ' ') FROM
    user INNER JOIN post ON post.user_id = user.id 

group by user.name
```